# Navbar with tabs in angular

Tags: css, angular, menu, navbar, bootstrap-5

Can someone tell me the best way to make a navbar in angular with tabs. The point is that it does not transfer to other subpages only after clicking on the tab a specific component is displayed. I will need it for an extended form. I don't want a separate path because the data can't disappear you need to be able to navigate between the data to fill.

Answer (score 1):

Use angular material stepper, you can switch between tabs.

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview